# checkbox value in a post array not in correct mysql row

Tags: php, html, arrays, checkbox

Hi i am trying to convert a input form field into a checkbox. in the input field i enter either 1 or 0 this works fine and stores correctly in MySQL database. I am trying to change the input field to a checkbox so `checked = 1` and `unchecked =0` .

When i change the input into a checkbox value it does not work correctly. The values get stored in the wrong rows in mysql. Could someone help please

```
<?php include('config.php'); ?>
<?php       $mm = "SELECT * FROM test_mysql";
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $mm) or die('-1'.mysqli_error());
 $count = $result->num_rows;
printf("Result set has %d rows.\n", $count);
// Count table rows 

?>

<table width="500" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<form  method="post" action="">
<tr> 
<td>
<table width="500" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">

<tr>
<td align="center"><strong>Id</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Name</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Lastname</strong></td>
<td align="center"><strong>Paid</strong></td>
</tr>

<?php
        while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $checked = $rows['paid'];
?>

<tr>
<td align="center">
<input name="id[]" type="text" id="id" value="<? echo $rows['id']; ?>">
</td>
<td align="center">
<input name="name[]" type="text" id="name" value="<? echo $rows['name']; ?>">
</td>
<td align="center">
<input name="lastname[]" type="text" id="lastname" value="<? echo $rows['lastname']; ?>">
</td>
<td align="center">
<?php /*?><input name="paid[]" type="text" id="paid" value="<? echo $rows['paid']; ?>"><?php */?>
</td>
<td align="center">
<input type="hidden" name="paid[]" value="0" />
<input type="checkbox" name="paid[]" value="1"<?php if ($checked == 1 ) echo 'checked' ?>/>

</td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
<tr>
<td colspan="4" align="center"> <button type="input" name="submit" value="editTask" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-icon"><i class="fa fa-check-square-o"></i>submit</button></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</form>
</table>
        <?php

// Check if button name "Submit" is active, do this 
if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == 'editTask'){
    $entryId = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['id']);

    foreach($_POST['id'] as $key=>$id) {

        $name = $_POST['name'][$key];
        $lastname = $_POST['lastname'][$key];
        $paid = $_POST['paid'][$key];
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE test_mysql SET name=?, lastname=?, paid=? WHERE id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('ssss', $name, $lastname, $paid,$id);
$stmt->execute();

}
$stmt->close();
header("location:page.php");
}
?>
```

Every work fine until i change the input paid into  a checkbox. What am I doing wrong. I have commented the input paid out as you can see in the code and added a hidden input called `name=paid[]` and checkbox `name=paid[]`

```
<input type="hidden" name="paid[]" value="0" />
<input type="checkbox" name="paid[]" value="1" <?php if ($checked == 1 ) echo 'checked' ?>/>
```

UPDATE When the paid[] post it does not post the  unchecked checkbox value=0
thanks
jon

SOLVED WITH HELP FROM @aimme

```
<input type="hidden" class="checkbox_handler" name="paid[]" value="<? echo $rows['paid']; ?>"<?php if ($checked == 1 ) echo 'checked' ?> />
<input type="checkbox" name="paidcheck[]" value="1" <?php if ($checked == 1 ) echo 'checked' ?>/>
```

add  JavaScript to change hidden value

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).on("change", "input[type='checkbox']", function() {
    var checkbox_val = ( this.checked ) ? 1 : 0;
    $(this).siblings('input.checkbox_handler').val(checkbox_val);
});</script>
```

thanks for your help!

Comment: Why did you use paid[] for email. <input name="paid[]" type="text" id="email" value="<? echo $rows['paid']; ?>">

Comment: remove space before checked `echo ' checked'?>/>`

Comment: sorry the id="email" i had changed to id="paid" and forgot to change the demo code i was working on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because the null values of check boxes are not posted with the form at all. This makes array to shift upward without including the null values. Use a hidden text box with each check-box as with no values in the text box at least the null will be posted with the form on submit.

Here is how you could achieve this with Jquery

```
<?php 
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST);
echo '</pre>';
$checked=0;
?>

<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <form method="post" action="">
<input type="hidden" name="paidHidden" id="paid" value="<?php echo ($checked == 1)?'1':'0'; ?>" />
<!-- for debugging to check whether it works
<input type="text" name="paidHidden" id="paid" value="0" />
-->
<input type="checkbox" name="dummy" id="dummy" <?php echo ($checked == 1)?'checked':''; ?>/>
<input type="submit" name="sub" />
</form> 
  <script>
      $("#dummy").click(function(){
          if ($(this).is(":checked"))
            {$("#paid").val(1);}
          else
          {$("#paid").val(0);}
      });
  </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice but i already have `<input type="hidden" name="paid[]" value="0" />
<input type="checkbox" name="paid[]" value="1" <?php if ($checked == 1 ) echo 'checked' ?>/>` in the form but still the values are not stored correctly. When i check the checkbox i get back `  [paid] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 0
            [3] => 1
            [4] => 0
            [5] => 1
            [6] => 0
            [7] => 0
            [8] => 1
            [9] => 0
        )` there should only be 6 entrys

Comment: ya i know. Use a javacript to detect the change on corresponding checkboxes and asign the values of checkboxes to the hidden text box before form is submitted. :) edited the code

Comment: How do i do that with javascript? Could you point me in the right direction please?

Comment: Ya sure .i am on that.

Comment: Solved the issue thanks for the help!! I have posted the working code  in an update to the original question thanks Aimme

Comment: at the same time i have updated the answer :) anyway this codes might help you even more :)