# Update multiple records from checkbox to database

Tags: php, mysql

`multiinput.php`

```
<form name="form" id="form" action="multiedit.php" method="post">

    <div id="show">        
    </div>
    <p><table>
        <tr>
            <th>Tick</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Rank</th>
            <th>Start Date</th>
            <th>End Date</th>
            <th>Watchkeeping</th>
            <th>Active</th>
        </tr> <!-- database -->
        <tr>
            <?php
            if (!mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {

                $queryStr = "SELECT * " .
                        "FROM crewlist";
            }
            $result = mysqli_query($con, $queryStr);
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                if (date("Y-m-d") > $row['start_date'] && date("Y-m-d") < $row['end_date']) {

                    echo "<tr><th>" . "<input type = 'checkbox' name = 'checkbox2[]' value='" . $row['crew_id']. "'>" . "</th>";
                    echo "<th>" . "<a href=\"viewcrew.php?id=" . $row['crew_id'] . "\">" . $row["crew_name"] . "</a>";
                    echo "<th>" . $row["crew_rank"] . "</th>";
                    echo "<th>" . $row["start_date"] . "</th>";
                    echo "<th>" . $row["end_date"] . "</th>";
                    echo "<th>" . $row["watchkeeping"] . "</th>";
                    echo "<th>" . $row["active"] . "</th>";
                } 
            }
            ?>

        </tr>
        <input type="submit" name="submit"value="Submit" ></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
    </form>
```

`multiedit.php`

```
<?php
require ("checkloginstatus.php");
include 'header.php'; ?>

<div id="container4"><?php
require ("dbfunction.php");
$con = getDbConnect();


$checkbox2 = $_POST['checkbox2'];

if (!mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
    $str = implode($checkbox2);

    $queryStr = "SELECT * " .
            "FROM crewlist WHERE  ($str)";
}

$result = mysqli_query($con, $queryStr);

if ($_POST['submit']) {
    $checkbox2 = $_POST['checkbox2'];
    foreach ($checkbox2 as $crewname) {

        ?> <form action="handlemultiedit.php" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="crew_id" value="<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>" />
        <?php echo "<tr><th>" . $crewname . ":</th><br>";
        echo "                    <tr>
                    <td>Shift 1:</td>
                    <td><input type=\"time\" name=\"start_hour\" value=\"start_hour\" id=\"start_hour\" step=\"1800\" required> to <input type=\"time\" name=\"end_hour\" value=\"end_hour\" id=\"end_hour\" step=\"1800\" required>
                    </td>       
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Shift 2:</td>
                    <td><input type=\"time\" name=\"start_hour2\" value=\"start_hour2\" id=\"start_hour2\" step=\"1800\" required> to <input type=\"time\" name=\"end_hour2\" value=\"end_hour2\" id=\"end_hour2\" step=\"1800\" required>
                    </td>       
                </tr><br><br>";
  //  print_r($_POST);
        ?>
            <?php
    }?>
            <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" ></td></form>
        <?php
}
?>
```

3) `handlemultiedit.php`

```
<?php

print_r($_POST);
require 'dbfunction.php';
$con = getDbConnect();
$crew_id = $_POST["crew_id"];

$start_hour = $_POST["start_hour"];
$end_hour = $_POST["end_hour"];
$start_hour2 = $_POST["start_hour2"];
$end_hour2 = $_POST["end_hour2"];

//if (!mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
//
//    $queryStr = "SELECT * " .
//            "FROM crewlist"; 
//
//$result = mysqli_query($con, $queryStr);
//}

if (isset ($_POST["submit"]) && $_POST['submit'] !=="") {
    $usercount = count ($_POST['crew_id']);
    for($i=0;$i<$usercount;$i++) {
    $sqlQueryStr = "UPDATE crewlist SET start_hour = '" .             $_POST["start_hour"] . "',end_hour = '$end_hour', start_hour2 = '$start_hour2',end_hour2 = '$end_hour2' WHERE crew_id = " . $crew_id . "";
mysqli_query($con, $sqlQueryStr);
}
}


//header('Location: crewlisting.php');
mysqli_close($con); 
?>
```

The flow of my webpage is `multiinput.php` to `multiedit.php` to handle `multiedit.php`

Not sure what went wrong but the update function is not working. I'm pretty sure there needs to be an ID passing from `multiedit.php` to `handlemultiedit.php`. P.S I'm new to php so please enlighten me on the mistakes and improvement. My intention is for the admin to multi select users using the checkboxes and click the submit button, which brings to their working schedule for the admin to edit them.

Comment: And where are you getting the error at? ;)

Comment: Currently this code has 0 error but it does not accomplish any update function, the print_r($_POST) only shows `Array ( [crew_id] => [start_hour] => 12:30 [end_hour] => 12:30 [start_hour2] => 12:30 [end_hour2] => 12:30 [submit] => Submit )` with no updates on the database whatsoever.

Comment: Then it could be something with your database, did you try changing your query to: `$sqlQueryStr = "UPDATE crewlist SET start_hour = '".$_POST["start_hour"]."', end_hour = '".$end_hour."', start_hour2 = '".$start_hour2."',end_hour2 = '".$end_hour2."' WHERE crew_id = ".$crew_id."";`

Comment: @Sina Yeap, I've tried them but to no avail. I suspect it is the passing of `crew_id` due to the multiple checkboxes.

Comment: I see, can you check that by passing something static to it? like: `crew_id = 456`? And then let me know :)

Comment: @Sina Oh! The static passing worked! So it might just so be the checkboxes' problem.

Comment: Have a look at aimme's solution then, that must do the trick :)

Comment: Although, reading your code again, why are you doing this `<input type="hidden" name="crew_id" value="" />` and expect a value back? it would be passing an empty value, no?

Comment: Yes that was the error i was initially talking about but i removed it to test my code again, so it was my fault, I'm going to edit in my initial code. it should be `input type="hidden" name="crew_id" value="<?php echo $_GET['id']" /?`

Comment: Well your edited code is wrong too mate, it should be: `<input type="hidden" name="crew_id" value="<?php echo $_GET['id'];?>" />`

Comment: Now after doing all that edition, what do you get in your `print_r`?

Comment: @Sina After all the edition, I still have the unidentified `Undefined index: id` as my error. aimme has a relatively complex function to me but it's an interesting one.

Comment: Then defining the `id` is the problem, not the checkboxes I guess. Have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Checkbox is little tricky in form submitting. Let me explain what happens when checkbox are used. If the checkbox is unchecked the checkbox is treated as even not posted although the form is submitted. But in case of text box if the textbox is empty null textbox will be posted on submit.
so in this case the unchecked array elements of the array `checkbox2[]` wont be submitted, shifting the array values only with the checked values. this makes the results wrong.

Example:
here is your form values

```
checkbox2[0] is checked // this will be submitted
checkbox2[1] is unchecked //this wont be submitted
checkbox2[2] is checked // this will be submitted
```

when the form is posted, data will look like this. wrong & not as expected

```
checkbox2[0]=checked
checkbox2[1]=checked
```

So the way to use multiple checkbox you could use a hidden textbox for each checkbox with javascript onchange to manupulate the hidden textbox value according to onchange or checked event of the corresponding checkbox.

[EDIT]
check this code

Additional Note: for debugging purpose add following php code to **multiedit.php** to see the submitted values

```
if($_POST){
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST);
echo '</pre>';
```

Edit the following section in your code like this

```
$i=0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                if (date("Y-m-d") > $row['start_date'] && date("Y-m-d") < $row['end_date']) {

                    //checkbox modified
                    echo "<tr><th>" . "<input type = 'checkbox' id='dummy[".$i."]' name = 'checkbox2[".$i."]' value='" . $row['crew_id']. "'>" . "</th>";
                    //added hidden textbox to carry value
                    echo "<input type ='hidden' id='h".$i."' name = 'htext[".$i."]'/>"; 

                    echo "<th>" . "<a href=\"viewcrew.php?id=" . $row['crew_id'] . "\">" . $row["crew_name"] . "</a>";
                    echo "<th>" . $row["crew_rank"] . "</th>";
                    echo "<th>" . $row["start_date"] . "</th>";
                    echo "<th>" . $row["end_date"] . "</th>";
                    echo "<th>" . $row["watchkeeping"] . "</th>";
                    echo "<th>" . $row["active"] . "</th>";
                    $i++;
                } 
}
```

Add following jquery to the bottom of the page. Remember to add jquery.js file to the header.

```
<script>
      $("input[type='checkbox']").click(function(){
          var i=$(this).attr("id").match(/\d+/);
          var v=$(this).attr("value");
          if ($(this).is(":checked"))
          {$("#h"+i).val(v);}
          else
          {$("#h"+i).val(null);}
      });

</script>
```

#### Additional: Do not conside below part as part of the answer

Hope this helps. i have tested and it works fine.

**For additional reference, here is the test.php that i used for testing, for better understanding**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="">
<?php
if($_POST){
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST);
echo '</pre>';
$checked=0;
}
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){
    echo "<input type = 'checkbox' id='dummy[".$i."]' name = 'checkbox2[".$i."]' value='my value" .$i. "'>";
    echo "<input type ='text' id='h".$i."' name = 'htext[".$i."]'/>"; 
}
?>
<input type="submit" name="sub" />
   <script>
      $("input[type='checkbox']").click(function(){
          var i=$(this).attr("id").match(/\d+/);
          alert(i);
          var v=$(this).attr("value");
          alert(v);
          if ($(this).is(":checked"))
          {$("#h"+i).val(v);}
          else
          {$("#h"+i).val(null);}
      });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've kinda got what you mean, but the difficulty level might be too high for me. Can you enlighten me with an example?

Comment: here is the jquery i have posted earlier to update hidden textbox according to the corresponding checkbox  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32412169/checkbox-value-in-a-post-array-not-in-correct-mysql-row/32412635#32412635. hope this gives you the idea to proceed. :)

Comment: I'd get back to you later, I'd need some time to digest, thanks tho :)

Comment: In my opinion this is an advanced feature for checkboxes but my main issue is the passing of the value from `multiinput.php` to `multiedit.php` . It's at line 27 of `multiedit.php`.